# QR code that contains a Windows Document Path

Tags: white-space, qrcode

in my LaTeX document, I need several QR codes in various places.
The QR codes should contain file paths in the form of Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\04 Picture. I intended to define the paths as a new command using `\newcommand{\qrpicpath}{Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\04 Picture}`, and then output it as a QR code using `\qrcode*{\qrpicpath}`.

However, the spaces are disappearing in the QR code. The output looks Like
Z:\01Customer\ProjectnameA\04Picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\qrpicpath}{\detokenize{Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\04 Picture}}

\begin{document}
  \qrcode*{\qrpicpath}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vanishing spaces between words inside a QRcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227127/vanishing-spaces-between-words-inside-a-qrcode)

Comment: I've already tried that. Unfortunately without success.
`\#newcommand*{\qrpicpath}{\detokenize{Z:\01\ Customer\Projectname\A\04\ Picture}} \qrcode[]{\qrpicpath}%`

results into Z:\01\Customer\Projectname\A\04\Picture

Comment: And if you don't detokenize it?

Comment: Also I think (but cannot verify now) that Windows also accepts forward slashes in paths instead of backslashes, that might make it easier because forward slashes don't need to be escaped.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that Windows also accepts slash forward. 
`\newcommand*{\qrpicpath}{Z:/01\ Customer/Projectname A/04\ Picture}` works fine.

But that makes it more difficult for the user because you can't simply copy the path in Explorer or you then have to edit it again.

Comment: Why can't you copy the path in Explorer? The slashes should be ok, and the escaped spaces are converted into normal spaces, so that should be fine too. By the way backslashes are of course also possible with escaping, i.e., `Z:\\01\ Customer\\Projectname A\\04\ Picture`. These will turn into single backslashes in the qrcode.

Comment: The QR code is part of a template. The template then defines the work instructions for a project. The person who creates the instruction copies the path from the explorer and then inserts it into the template. There will be about 7 paths all in Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\ and a lot (about 50) of white variables.
Whether the creator accepts that a \ must be used for every space in the path requires convincing :-).

Comment: Ah I see, I thought you meant to copy the path from the QR reader into the Explorer, but you actually meant the other way around, to copy the path from the Explorer into the LaTeX code. This indeed does not work without some additional preprocessing. Maybe you can put some post-processing in the pipeline before calling LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\rescan{\tl_set_rescan:Nnn}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\rescan \qrpicpath{\catcode`\ =12 \catcode`\\=12}{Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\04 Picture}
\begin{document}
  \qrcode*{\qrpicpath}
\end{document}
```

```
<QR code requested for "Z:\01 Customer\Projectname A\04 Picture" in version 0-M
.>
```